# Initial value problem uniqueness (Lipschitz)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that each of the following initial-value problems has a unique solution ($0 ≤ t ≤ 1 , y(0) = 1$).

$$y' = \exp(t-y)$$

**Theorem 1**: Suppose that $D=\{(t,y)|a≤t≤b, −∞< y<∞\}$ and that $f(t,y)$ is continuous on $D$. If $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition on $D$ in the variable $y$, then the initial-value problem $y′(t)=f(t,y)$, $a≤t≤b$, $y(a)=α$, has a unique solution $y(t) for a ≤ t$ ≤ b.

Can theorem 1 be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem cannot be applied directly since the function $e^{t-y}$ is not Lipschitz. However, we can work around this by noting that $y$ must always be positive, as $y(0)>0$ and $y'(t)>0$ for all $t$. Thus we can replace $y'=e^{t-y}$ with
$$y'=\begin{cases}
e^{t-y} &\text{if } y > 0\\
e^t &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
without changing the problem, and this function is indeed Lipschitz, so theorem 1 can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't apply the theorem directly, as $f(t,y) = e^{t-y}$ is not uniformly Lipschitz on $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $ t\in [a,b]$.

However, you could take $\tilde{f}(t,y) = e^{t-|y|}$, which **is** uniformly Lipschitz on $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $ t\in [a,b]$. Then $\dot{\tilde{y}} = f(t,\tilde{y})$ has a unique solution for $ t\in [a,b]$. Since $\tilde{f}(t,y) >0$ everywhere, if $\tilde{y}(0)>0$, then we have $\tilde{y}(t) \ge \tilde{y}(0) >0$ for all $t\ge 0$.

So, suppose $\tilde{y}$ is the unique solution to $\dot{\tilde{y}} = f(t,\tilde{y})$, with $\tilde{y}(0) = y(0) = 1$.

Now we need to connect this equation with the original problem: If $y\ge 0$, then $f(t,y) = \tilde{f}(t,y)$, and since $\tilde{y}(t) \ge 1$ for all $t \ge 0$, we see that $\tilde{y}$ is ***a*** solution to the original problem. Hence a solution exists. to see that it is unique, notice that any solution $y$ also satisfies $\dot{y}(t) \ge 0$, hence $y(t)\ge 1$ for all $t \ge 0$. Hence $f(t,y(t)) = \tilde{f}(t,y(t))$ for $t \ge 0$, and so $y$ satisfies the modified differential equation, and so we have $y = \tilde{y}$. Hence the solution is unique.